# Where can we define repositories to be used for Docker?

Tags: docker

By default docker connects to Docker Hub registry, where is this configured in Ubuntu OS?

If we need to point to our own corporate repository or any other repository, where can we configure the same?

Comment: Hi there! Did you find your way with this?

Comment: ah! yes. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the [`docker pull`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/#pull-from-a-different-registry) reference:

> ## Pull from a different registry
>
> By default, `docker pull` pulls images from [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/). It is also possible to manually specify the path of a registry to pull from. For example, if you have set up a local registry, you can specify its path to pull from it. A registry path is similar to a URL, but does not contain a protocol specifier (`https://`).
>
> The following command pulls the `testing/test-image` image from a local registry listening on port 5000 (`myregistry.local:5000`):
>
> ```
> $ docker pull myregistry.local:5000/testing/test-image
> ```

As you may notice, at the end there is also a link to [insecure registries](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#insecure-registries) because you might need to further configure the Docker daemon.